# what is the best practice for selecting extended entities in EF5,

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I use linq to entities to query the DB, sometimes I need to bring extra information from the joined tables (without navigational property),I extended the entity to hold the info, my question is how can I set the extra properties without having to remap all it's base properties.

ex

```
from s in db.t1 
join p in db.t2 on s.indx equals p.indx into ps
from c in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()  
select new t1() { p1 = s.p1, p2 = s.p2 ..., extra = c.extra }
```

so can I set just the 'extra' value in a fast way !

Comment: Why don't you create a view and map your entity to the view?

Comment: the code i have is working fine, i'm looking for a shorter method if available (in the select part)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use an anonymous object?

```
from s in db.t1 
join p in db.t2 on s.indx equals p.indx into ps
from c in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()  
select new
{ 
    p1 = s.p1, 
    p2 = s.p2,
    extra = c.extra 
}
```

Comment: i know, i'm wondering if there is some way to only assign the extra values without having to remap the main properties